# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in ___ on line 51

Tags: php, syntax

I'm trying to fetch a single row.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mydb", "joakim", "password", "db");

$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(dato, '%e. %b kl %H:%i') AS fdato FROM bidrag WHERE bidrag_id = $bidrag_id";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)

return $row; <--- This line
```

However this makes this error message:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in /iu/cube/u0/s181322/www/prosjekt/klasser/Bidrag.php on line 51**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a semicolon after the penultimate line (`$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)`)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon `;` on the line before the error. Keep in mind that when getting an error in PHP, 9/10 times the error isn't on the line indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a semicolon after the line before :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mydb", "joakim", "password", "db");

$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(dato, '%e. %b kl %H:%i') AS fdato FROM bidrag WHERE bidrag_id = $bidrag_id";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); // There

return $row;
```